# Is the symbol in the images a chinese letter?

Tags: translation, character-identification

Is the symbol in the images a chinese letter, and if it is, what does it mean?

[image: image1]
[image: image2] 
[image: image3]
[image: image4]
[image: imagev]
[image: image6]

Comment: I'm only qualified to say I don't recognize it. In order to say not , I need to know all the characters. There are a lot of stuff on oracle bones I don't knoe.

Comment: What is the context of these images?

Answer (score 6):

I saw this image on Walt Disney's tie in a picture of him.  It is not a Chinese character, rather the letters S, R and T, according to : http://www.quora.com/Saving-Mr-Banks-2013-film/What-is-the-logo-mark-on-Walt-Disneys-tie .

Comment: yes it does: http://www.quora.com/Saving-Mr-Banks-2013-film/What-is-the-logo-mark-on-Walt-Disneys-tie

Comment: @MasterSparkles Now it does. Thanks for updating the answer!

Answer (score 3):

It certainly has the feel of a Chinese character, though I don't recognize it as anything modern. At first glance, it seemed to be a smudged/misformed 束. However, upon closer inspection, it could be 䖝, a variant/corrupted form of 蟲(虫) meaning insect.

If you look at the entry under a03683-003 on http://dict.variants.moe.edu.tw/yitia/yda/yda03683.htm, it seems very similar.

Furthermore, there are multiple entries under http://en.glyphwiki.org/wiki/twedu-a03683-004 which bear a strong resemblance to the image you posted, namely u459d-04-var-001 / u459d-14-var-001 and u459d-ue0102 (just search for those entries in your browser).

Keep in mind that Chinese characters have been used in other languages and they have been modified or simplified over time, resulting in these variant forms.

Answer (score 2):

where did you see this character? it looks like it could be the flipped image of the character for "免“ which means

```
(Min Nan) it is not necessary; there is no need
```

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%85%8D

(flipped image)

[image: image flipped horizontally]

Comment: No, I am sure it was in the correct orientation in the image. Good thinking though

Answer (score 0):

The flipped version @ljk provided somehow reminds me of the character 兔 (rabbit), even it doesn't looks like one.

Comment: Because the Japanese version of 兔, which is 兎, looks exactly like the flipped image with the addition of a dot. But this word is pronounced as *usagi* in Japanese, and nothing to do with "Smoke Tree Ranch" (STR).